# Expectation of a binomial random variable raised to a non-integer power? ("non-integer moment" of a probability distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Does anyone know if there's a closed-form expression of the expectation of the maximum likelihood estimator of a binomial variable raised to a non-integer power?

Concretely, setting
$$
P(m\mid N,p) = \binom{N}{m} p^m (1-p)^{N-m},\\
\hat{p} = \frac{m}{N}.
$$

What is $E[\hat{p}^w]$, where $0<w<1$?

Specifically
$$
E[\hat{p}^w]
 = \sum_{m=0}^N \binom{N}{m} p^m (1-p)^{N-m} \left(\frac{m}{N}\right)^w =~?
$$

If $w$ was integer we could use the moment-generating function. Is there an analogous function that generates the "non-integer moments" of probability distributions?

Comment: No idea, but if you only need one value of $w$, perhaps try simulation?

Comment: This is just an intermediate result for me so I would like to have a closed form to see how my final results depend on the params. But more generally, I'd like to know if there's any clever concept like the moment generating function that can work for non-integer powers.

Comment: A first-order Delta method would suggest $E[\hat{p}^w] \approx p^w$.